# Python ASK signal plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot the following 3 signals in Python (Spyder). Bellow, I have indicated photos of the signal that my code needs to plot. (The first one I manage to plot it successfully.)
[image]

Furthermore, the code needs to plot the square signal from the array word [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]. (Which I haven't figure how to do it the proper way)

[image]

Last, the following signal should be plotted from the above 2 signals.

[image]

In a previous post here (stack overflow) I get some help in order to plot the square signal. However, I think this is not the way to do it since I am receiving the following error when I am trying to plot the 3rd signal.

```
ASK_signal=pliroforia*our_signal

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1440000,) (250,)
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Below is my code so far:

```
import fft_modules
from fft_modules import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, linspace, sin, cos, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy import *

A=1                                                 
f=1000
T=1/f                                          
B=f                                            
Nyquist_Fs=2*B                                 
Fs=100*Nyquist_Fs                              
Ts=T/10                                        
Tmax=25*T                                      
samples_per_period=T/Ts                        
total_samples=samples_per_period*(Tmax/T)      

print("TS="+str(Ts))
print("T="+str(T))

t = linspace(0, Tmax, total_samples, endpoint=True)

#our_signal = signal.square(A*cos(2*pi*f*t))
our_signal = A*sin(2*pi*f*t)


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,our_signal)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')



word = array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
Samples_per_bit=int(12/Ts)
pliroforia=[]
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    table=np.ones(Samples_per_bit)
    x=table*word[i]
    pliroforia=np.concatenate((pliroforia,x))

t = linspace(0, Tmax, pliroforia.shape[0], endpoint=True)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t,pliroforia)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')


ASK_signal=pliroforia*our_signal
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t,ASK_signal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from incompatible shape between your arrays.
You have to make sure that both `pliroforia` and `our_signal` have the same number of elements before computing their product.

I think that is what you try to achieve with your `for` loop.
But it should not work as you expect.

What you have here is a problem of "resampling" (I am not sure that it is the right word, but it can help in search engine).
You have two series, ranging from time 0 to time `Tmax` (which is 0.25 here), one with `total_samples` (250) samples, the other with only 12 samples.
You want to resample your second serie up to 250 samples, to have compatible shape.

This is a common problem, and most good libraries have a "resampling" operation.
In scipy, it is called [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d).
You call it with the x and y values of your "short" serie and it gives you a function that you can call with a new array of x values at which you want to sample your initial serie (this is not very clear, look at the code, an example worth thousands words).

So here is the resulting code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def main():
    frequency=1000
    period=1/frequency
    duration=25*period
    samples_per_period=10
    total_samples=int(samples_per_period*(duration/period))

    t = np.linspace(0, duration, total_samples, endpoint=True)
    waving_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi * frequency * t)

    word = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])  # -> array of size 12
    word_x_values = np.linspace(0, duration, word.shape[0])  # These 12 samples cover the same duration as the waving signal -> array of shape 12
    word_interpolator = interp1d(word_x_values, word, kind="previous")  # Get an interpolator for this serie
    resampled_word = word_interpolator(t)  # Get a new serie with same sampling as the waving signal -> array of size 250

    # Now you can mix the signals as the series have compatible shapes
    mixed_signal = resampled_word * waving_signal

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex="col")
    axes[0].plot(t, waving_signal)
    axes[1].plot(t, resampled_word)
    axes[2].plot(t, mixed_signal)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the resulting plot.

[image]

---

### Edit

I just noticed that my word signal does not match what you expect.
This is caused by a "bad" x values generation.
The 12 samples of `word` do not cover the whole `duration`.

To fix this, you can either use more arguments (which I think is semantically more correct):

```py
word = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
# Use the endpoint argument as these samples do not cover up to the whole duration
word_x_values = np.linspace(0, duration, word.shape[0], endpoint=False)
# Initial x values do not cover the whole duration range
# You have to handle this with bounds_error and fill_value
word_interpolator = interp1d(
    word_x_values, word, kind="previous",
    bounds_error=False, fill_value=(word[0], word[-1])
)
resampled_word = word_interpolator(t)
```

Another solution which is maybe easier but convey less meaning is to add a sample to `word` making it covering the whole duration:

```py
word = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
word.append(word[-1])
word = np.array(word)  # Duplicate the last sample
# No more change
word_x_values = np.linspace(0, duration, word.shape[0])  # -> array of shape 13
word_interpolator = interp1d(word_x_values, word, kind="previous")
resampled_word = word_interpolator(t)
```

Now, the word signal is more like what you expect (starting and ending with a full 1 bit):

[image]